# Is there a way in SwiftData to insert new items without updating potential already existing ones (and without creating duplicates)?

Tags: swift, swift-data

I have a long list of (let's say movies) items stored already and this list can be refreshed to pull out potential new items from an API.

```
@Model
final class Movie: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) let code: String
    let name: String
    ...
    var favorite: Bool?

    init(code: String, name: String, ..., favorite: Bool? = false) {
    self.code = code
    self.name = name
    ...
    self favorite = favorite ?? false
  }
}
```

I have a function that fetches all the movies from an API and then do (for each movie) a modelContext.insert(movie).

Now, obviously, the movies from the API aren't marked as favorite already and for new movies, the default `false` applies and this is good. However, due to SwiftData default behavior, already existing movies get 'updated' (as to not create a duplicate) and thus set back to the default favorite `false`.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to find and update the movies manually but it might be better to just restructure your database.

Have a `MovieModel` and a much simpler `FavoriteMovieModel` that has a `Relationship` with `MovieModel`.

Then you can check the relationship to see if it is a favorite.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but whenever I insert new movies, the relationship FavoriteMovieModel gets updated as well and thus I end up facing the same dilemma.

Comment: @Kawameicha this is very odd you might have to resort to an implied relationship by just saving the code then. Maybe a UserModel with a favorites array. I would submit a bug report it seems like it is almost missing something g similar to “decode if present”

Comment: Agreed, it is strange. I eventually managed to have it work using a `FavoriteMovieModel` without the relationship to `MovieModel`, updating the later with the values stored in the `FavoriteMovieModel` after fetching the API and before the modelContext.insert() but this doesn't feel right.